# Adding a "comment" to PGP mail signature files?

Tags: pgp, digital-signature

I have started signing my mail with PGP, and it attaches the file `signature.asc` to my messages to verify that I sent them with content, as you'd expect, like this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=Xyfk
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

Is it possible to include a "comment" with the signature file? If someone uses PGP/GPG they will just see a message that the email was signed. But most people I send mail to do not use PGP, so they will see this attachment and perhaps will be confused - is it possible to include a "comment" in this file (ideally auto-generated) which explains that what the signature means to the uninitiated?

Answer (score 6):

OpenPGP, [RFC 4880 "Forming ASCII Armor"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-6.2), defines a way to add comments to ASCII-armored OpenPGP data.

Using GnuPG (no matter whether using GPGTools or not), this comment can be configured using the `comment` option, either as `gpg --comment` or in the GnuPG config file `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`, for example

```
comment Comment you want to add in each file.
```

The Apple Mail plugin does not overwrite the option, thus the comment will also be added to mails sent using Apple Mail.

Comment: ok `gpg.conf` is a trick I haven't thought of. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. See [this](http://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=libgcrypt.git;a=blob;f=README;h=f25ff6f91efc6d2034fdef0a1ba21040ab99163a;hb=e596b8962e6711718dccab14f503984d37d323fe) as an example. [RFC 2440](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2440) allows arbitrary comment lines starting with "`Comment:`":

> Currently defined Armor Header Keys are:
>
> - "Version", that states the OpenPGP Version used to encode the
>        message.
> - "Comment", a user-defined comment.
> - [...]

The spec is silent about whether multiple comments may be specified but with my tests with `gpg --verify` it accepted multiple comments.

Changing or adding comments (for example with a text editor) doesn't make the signature invalid, as they are not part of the signed message.

Theroretically it is possible to use them, but for [GPGTools](https://gpgtools.org/gpgmail/) I can't think of a way to add them on an automated basis. Note that I came to this conclusion through review of the [source code](https://github.com/GPGTools/GPGMail/blob/dev/Source/GPGMailPreferences.m), and a screenshot on [this site](http://gpgtools.github.io/GPGTools_Homepage/gpgmail/).

You can however add a "[signature](http://macs.about.com/od/appleconsumersoftware/qt/Add-A-Signature-To-Your-Email-Messages-In-Apple-Mail.htm)" to your email telling about the asc file and its contents.

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate more on how to do this practically?

Comment: Which tool do you use?

Comment: GPGTools for mac

Answer (score 1):

I put a comment at the end of the message *text* (part of a sig, really), where people are much more likely to see it:
[About PGP signatures (http://xkcd.com/1181)](http://xkcd.com/1181/)